# Определения «помятую» и «отросшую» однородны?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

*Пригладив **помятую, отросшую** бороду, я шумно выдохнул, отчаянно пытаясь успокоить бешено колотящееся в груди сердце.*

Можно ли считать прилагательные "помятую" и "отросшую" однородными и нужна ли между ними запятая?

Answer (score 2):

Первое. *Помятый* и *отросший* — это не прилагательные, а **причастия** (от *помять* и *отрасти*).

Второе. Думаю, что их можно считать однородными, в этом случае запятая нужна (*пригладив помятую **и** отросшую бороду*).

> Между однородными определениями, не связанными союзами, ставится **запятая**.
> Согласованные определения являются однородными:
> 3) если в условиях контекста, характеризуя предмет с разных сторон, объединяются каким-либо общим признаком (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному общему понятию, причинно-следственной связью и т. д.)...

Третье. Часто выбор — ставить или не ставить запятую? — делает сам автор, обыгрывая контекст, создавая то или иное впечатление.
Вот, например, у того же Розенталя: ***густой, чёрный дым*.**
Если мы заглянем в [Нацкорпус](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=0&req=%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BC&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform), то выяснится, что примеров с запятой в этом сочетании там только одиннадцать (из сорока).

Вот, у одного и того же автора:
**Густой черный дым** валил из левого «Юнкерса» и заволакивал его всего... Пламени не было видно, ― может быть, оттого, что солнечный свет был слишком ярок, ― но **густой, черный дым** тянулся за самолетом расширяющейся полосой чуть ли не через всё небо. [Н. К. Чуковский. Балтийское небо (1946-1953)]

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)

Дополнительное. Запятая перед вторым союзом "и" в формулировке вопроса не нужна:
*Можно ли считать прилагательные "помятую" и "отросшую" однородными **и** нужна ли между ними запятая?*

> **3.** Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:
> **1)** вопросительные предложения: *Это кто такие **и** что им надобно?* (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация...

[Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

Comment: Помятая, потому что отросшая? А какая здесь связь? И пояснение не связано с однородностью. И об этом сказано у Розенталя: Так называемые пояснительные определения однородными не являются; запятая между ними ставится, если второе определение поясняет первое.

Comment: В правиле (по ссылке, чуть дальше): Раздался страшный, оглушительный удар грома (‘страшный, потому что оглушительный’); Наступили тяжёлые, мрачные времена (‘тяжелые, поэтому и мрачные’); Он прикрыл глаза красными, воспалёнными веками (‘красными, потому что воспаленными’)

Comment: Дело не в применении "потому что". *Помятая, потому что отросшая* — отросшая борода должна быть помятой? В этой фразе нет логики.

Comment: Не должна, но может. Вполне возможно, что коротенькая борода была опрятной, а вот отросшая — нет. Всё зависит от контекста. Он вспоминал запах бульваров и, несмотря на дряблый живот и **беспорядочно отросшую бороду**, изобразил на лице молодое лукавство: [А. Н. Толстой. Хождение по мукам/ Книга третья. Хмурое утро (1941)]

Comment: А коротенькая тоже может быть отросшей. Может, раньше у него была коротенькая. Всё-таки там нет пояснения. Другое дело, если была бы длинной. Ещё важно учитывать, что прочтение однородных определений и определений с пояснением очень отличается.

Comment: Согласна. Я поэтому и привела в ответе розенталевское сочетание (густой, чёрный дым) в качестве примера: кто-то ставит запятую (их меньше), а кто-то не ставит.

Comment: Но там есть логика: густой, потому что чёрный (серый не настолько густой). Или густой и чёрный. Или чёрный дым является густым. Все три варианта уместны.

Comment: В связи с этим всем считаю, что "*(помятая, потому что отросшая)*" лучше из ответа убрать. В любом случае к однородности, о которой говорится, это отношения не имеет. Можно заменить на "помятая и отросшая".

Comment: Как скажете, *oleedd*. Можно и так, по-простому.

Answer (score 0):

Почему мой ответ удалили? Что это за беспредел? Я могу сколько угодно ошибаться, заблуждаться и т.д., но мой ответ имеет право на существование; тем более в такого рода неоднозначных ситуациях. Верните мой ответ, так как это полный беспредел.

Comment: Потому что он не отвечает на вопрос (однородны или нет, нужна ли запятая?).

Comment: Да, но если там присутствует речевая избыточность, то вопрос об однородных членах уже не имеет значения.

Comment: Не факт, автора может интересовать ответ даже и при избыточности.

Comment: А я считаю, что нет здесь никакой избыточности. Вполне приемлемое сочетание для художественного текста.

Comment: В лубом случае нельзя просто так удалять вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Не часто говорят, что отросшая борода помятая или что-то типа того, поэтому "*помятая {отросшая борода}*" не очень звучит и лучше с запятой. Но и без запятой допустимо, потому что определения не особо однородны — состояние (помятая) и то, что с ней произошло (отросла после сбривания).

Ориентируйтесь по паузе и ударениям:
*Пригладив помЯтую, отросшую бОроду...* || На первом определении есть ударение.
*Пригладив помятую отросшую бОроду...* || На первом определении нет ударения.

Разница:
С запятой: *борода помятая и отросшая*.
Без запятой: *отросшая борода помятая*.
Не обязательно определения при запятой однородны, просто тогда они независимо относятся к существительному.
При запятой очень важно то, что определения можно поменять местами. Здесь это допустимо, хоть и становится хуже, что свидетельствует о некоторой неоднородности:
*Пригладив отросшую, помятую бороду...*